# Front end registration form, no errors

Tags: user-profile, frontend, registration

I'm using the following modified version of the user [registration form](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/user-registration-form) for the purpose of a user updating their details.

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form form--full">

    {{ getCsrfInput() }}

    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="users/saveUser">
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="profile">
    <input type="hidden" name="userId" value="{{ currentUser.id }}">

    <fieldset>
        <legend class="visually-hidden">Personal details</legend>
        {{ account is defined ? _self.errorList(account.getAllErrors()) : 'not' }}

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="firstName">First name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName" value="{{ currentUser.firstName }}" placeholder="First name" required="required" aria-required="true" autofocus="autofocus">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="lastName">Last name<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="lastName" type="text" name="lastName" value="{{ currentUser.lastName }}" placeholder="Surname" required="required" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="email">Email<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="{{ currentUser.email }}" placeholder="Email address" required="required" aria-required="true" disabled="disabled">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="mobileNumber">Phone / Mobile number</label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="mobileNumber" type="tel" name="fields[mobileNumber]" placeholder="Phone number" value="{{ currentUser.mobileNumber }}" aria-required="false">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="company">Company / Organisation<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="company" type="text" name="fields[company]" value="{{ currentUser.company }}" limit="150" placeholder="Company" required="required" aria-required="true">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="position">Position</label>
            <div class="form__input">
                <input id="position" type="text" name="fields[position]" value="{{ currentUser.position }}" placeholder="Position" aria-required="false">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form__group">
            <label class="form__pullLabel" for="profilePhoto">Profile photo</label>
            <div class="form__input imageSelect">
                {% if currentUser.photoUrl %}
                    <img src="{{ currentUser.photoUrl }}" id="userPhoto" /><input type="hidden" name="deleteUserPhoto" id="deleteUserPhotoInput" value="">{% else %}<img src="{{ url(siteSettings.defaultUserImage.first.getUrl()) }}" width="100" alt="no profile image" />{% endif %}<input id="profilePhoto" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" name="userPhoto" value="{{ (currentUser.photoUrl ? 'Change Photo' : 'Upload') }}">
                {% if currentUser.photoUrl %}
                    <a id="deleteUserPhotoAction" class="button button--reverse ut-marginTop">Delete</a>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <button class="spinnerHolder button button--full" type="submit">Save details</button>
   </fieldset>

</form>
```

This updates, however I can't seem to get any errors for empty fields

Does anything look off? If not, can you perhaps give a push in the right direction as to why it may not be working?

Thanks

Comment: `_self.errorList(account.getAllErrors())` - have you actually defined a macro called `errorList`? Your example code doesn't show it.

Comment: Sorry for not including. Yes I have, above the content as in the documentation example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem wasn't what I initially expected

After a bit of searching, I found out that the default first name and last name fields are not required by default and there's no way to make them required. As a result, validation wasn't failing; hence no `account` object to get errors from

My solution was to just create two extra custom fields `User First Name` and `User Last Name`. Not ideal, but solves the problem